# PHP sort 2d array by index (non-associative)

Tags: php, sorting

This code does not run properly, but it suggests what I am trying to do:

```
function sort_2d_by_index($a,$i) {
  function cmp($x, $y) {
    // Nested function, can't find $i
    // (global $i defeats the purpose of passing an arg)
    if ($x[$i] == $y[$i]) { return 0; }
    return ($x[$i] < $y[$i]) ? -1 : 1;
  }

  usort($a,"cmp");
  return $a;
}
```

There HAS to be a much better way to do this.  I've been examining `ksort()`, `multisort()`, and all sorts of sorts until I'm sort of tired trying to sort it all out.

The situation is this: I've got a 2-d array...

```
array(
  array(3,5,7),
  array(2,6,8),
  array(1,4,9)
);
```

...and I want to sort by a column index.  Say, column `[1]`, would give this result:

```
array(
  array(1,4,9),
  array(3,5,7),
  array(2,6,8)
);
```

Does someone have a link (I'm sure this has been asked before), or could someone say "you need `foosort`, definitely".  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) of `array_multisort` it is mentioned that it can be used for this kind of thing.

You can't avoid creating an array that consists of only one column:

```
$sort_column = array();
foreach ($a as $row)
    $sort_column []= $row[1]; // 1 = your example

array_multisort($sort_column, $a);
```

This sorts both arrays synchronously so that afterwards your whole array is sorted in the same order as the $sort_column array is.

As of PHP 5.3 you can use a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (pass `$i` into the function) by defining your `cmp` function like this:

```
$cmp = function($x, $y) use ($i) { ... };
```

Comment: Thanks for the closure link, too.  Turns out the `array_multisort` solution is The One, until PHP 5.3 is more widespread.  I had had a look at the documentation but didn't find an explanation as good as this one. Too bad I can't accept twice, this answer is great :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `use` to access `$i`:

```
function cmp($x, $y) use ($i) {
    // $i now available
    if ($x[$i] == $y[$i]) { return 0; }
    return ($x[$i] < $y[$i]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#99419

> phpdotnet at m4tt dot co dot uk
>
> Simple function to sort an array by a specific key. Maintains index association.