# sorting 2d array with individual comparator using phps array_multisort

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, comparator

I got a 2d-array containing a "column" on which this whole array is to be sorted. As I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262517/php-sort-2d-array-by-index-non-associative), it is quite straightforward using `array_multisort`. My problem is, that this *to be sorted over* column contains values that needs to be compared in an unusual way. So I thought of something like this:

```
function main(){
    $toBeSorted = array(array(...), ..., array(...));
    $sortColumnIndex = n;
    $sort_column = array();

    //Code copied from provided link
    foreach ($toBeSorted as $row)
        $sort_column []= $row[$sortColumnIndex];

    array_multisort($this->comparator(),$sort_column, $toBeSorted);
}

function comparator(a,b){
    return 1;
}
```

As you can see, I want to pass my comparator to that sort-function. I probably think to much in a non-php way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by transforming my sorting space in one, that array_multisort can handle:

```
...

$sortColumn = array();
foreach($toBeSorted as $value){
     $sortColumn[] = $this->transform($value);
}
array_multisort($sortColumn, $toBeSorted);

...
```

my transformation function simply does everything I imagined the callback would do.

```
function transform($value){
    //i.e. return real part of complex number
    //or parse strings or any kind of strange datatypes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the [usort](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function, which sorts by using a callback.

Otherwise you could have a look at the [array_walk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) functions, which iterate over an array and apply a function to every member.

Comment: is there another function that works like usort but returns an array of positions of the elements? Just like pythons `numpy.argsort`? Because otherwise I cannot keep track of the other columns to sort the 2d-arrays?

Comment: I don't think it exists. [This is the list](http://be.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) of all array sorting functions in PHP.